# Programmatically add javascript in html page

Tags: javascript, html, eval

I'm trying to build an HTML page like this

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function setup(){
        var mydesign = '<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="BtnClick()" /><div id=result></div>';
        var myscript = 'function BtnClick(){alert("DoTest()");}';
        eval(myscript);     
        document.getElementById("myBody").innerHTML = mydesign;
      }             
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id = "myBody" onload="setup()">
  </body>
</html>
```

But `onclick` cannot find function `BtnClick()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to add a script programmatically? This just smells bad design considering innerHTML, inline listeners and eval ...

Comment: Obligatory [eval is bad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) comment.

Comment: The design and functionality is defined from a "master" system (an erp to be specific) according to misc parameters. The page will call the master system (through webservices) and get what needs to be shown and what has to be done on events.

Comment: `BtnClick` is local to the scope of `setup`, due to the way you implemented this. The onclick attribute on the button expects it to be a function in the global scope however.

Comment: The issue was the scope and the solution was this.eval("....."). Many Thanks CBroe.

Comment: All this could be achieved with simple functions. Adding a function string to a script and then evaluating it doesn't save any bandwidth or memory. On the contrary, there's extra code for evaluating strings, and the result of `eval` is not optimized with best availabe optimizations, as a real code would be. If there will be a ton of unused functions, I'd consider to add the missing scripts dynamically from external sources, or the most preferrably way, import functions using modules when needed. By no means to be offensive, but the current design looks like it was made in 1999 ...

Comment: And one more thing ... if this is somehow related to authorization, then the approach is totally incorrect, you can't autohorize anything on the client-side, always do that on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

`The eval() function evaluates or executes an argument`

create BtnClick() function separate as below

```js
function BtnClick(){
                alert("DoTest()");
            }
            function setup() {
                var mydesign = '<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="BtnClick()" /><div id=result></div>';
                document.getElementById("myBody").innerHTML = mydesign;
            }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>JS</title>
    </head>
    <body id="myBody" onload="setup()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't initally know how many button will be created and how many different functions will have to be built

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write js functions directly into the `onclick` attribute

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body id = "myBody" onload="setup()">

<script type="text/javascript">

    function setup(){
        var mydesign = "<button onclick="+'alert("hello")'+">Click me</button>";
        document.getElementById("myBody").innerHTML = mydesign;
    }               
</script>
</body>
</html>
```